# Insertion order in nested map c++

Tags: c++

I currently have a nested `map< int, map < int, char > > m;`. I have 2 int values as keys for x,y coordinates and I save a char `m[x][y]='A'. I tried inserting the values into a vector`map< vector, map< vector, char> > m;` but didn't work. Is there a way to keep track of order of char saved to the map?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why you use this ugly _map in map_?
`struct point { int x; int y; }; map<point, char> m;`
or
`map<pair<int,int>, char> m;`
seems better, isn't it?

Comment: @renzo unless you want all populated y coordinates of a particular x coordinate efficiently. I don't know why OP would need it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep track of order of char saved to the map?

Yes. You can copy the returned iterator when you insert into the map, and push that iterator into a vector. Elements pushed into a vector remain in the insertion order, so it will keep track for you. Alternatively you might just push the char value, depending on what you want to keep track of - the character or the map element. Also, you might need to store a pair of both the inner and outer iterators depending how you use them.

Note that you must use `std::map::insert` to get the iterator instead of `operator[]`.